# Random unique string against a blacklist

Tags: random, unique, uuid, blacklist

I want to create a random string of a fixed length (8 chars in my use case) and the generated string has to be case sensitive and unique against a blacklist. I know this sounds like a UUID but I have a specific requirement that prevents me from utilizing them

1. some characters are disallowed, i.e. I, l and 1 are lookalikes, and O and 0 as well

My initial implementation is solid and solves the task but performs poorly. And by poorly I mean it is doomed to be slower and slower every day.

This is my current implementation I want to optimize:

```
private function uuid()
{
    $chars = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTVUWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstvuwxyz23456789';

    $uuid = null;
    while (true) {
        $uuid = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 8);

        if (null === DB::table('codes')->select('id')->whereRaw('BINARY uuid = ?', [$uuid])->first())) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return $uuid;
}
```

Please spare me the critique, we live in an agile world and this implementation is functional and is quick to code.

With a small set of data it works beautifully. However if I have 10 million entries in the blacklist and try to create 1000 more it fails flat as it takes 30+ minutes.

A real use case would be to have 10+ million entries in the DB and to attempt to create 20 thousand new unique codes.

I was thinking of pre-seeding all allowed values but this would be insane:
(24+24+8)^8 = 9.6717312e+13

It would be great if the community can point me in the right direction.

Best,
Nikola

Comment: Does it need to be unpredictable/unguessable?  What are the reasons you can't simply use an incrementing counter?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it has to be unpredictable. Think of voucher codes.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Just use a hash of something unique, and truncate so it fits in the bandwidth of your identifier.  Hashes sometimes collide, so you will still need to check the database and retry if a code is already in use.

   ```
   s = "This is a string that uniquely identifies voucher #1.  Blah blah."
   h = hash(s)
   guid = truncate(hash)
   ```
2. Generate five of the digits from an incrementing counter and three randomly.  A thief will have a worse than 1 in 140,000 chance of guessing a code, depending on your character set.

   ```
   u = Db.GetIncrementingCounter()
   p = Random.GetCharacters(3)
   guid = u + p
   ```

Comment: Do you know a hash whose output is case sensitive? I can't think of any on top of my head.
However your response brought me on to two ideas:
1) Split the RDBS table from one column for the uuid into 3 or more columns. Goal is to speed up DB check by having a more granular WHERE clause.
2) Try NoSQL for storing and checking the blacklist.
I'll try them both later today.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the approach: instead of checking for uuid existence on every loop, e.g. 50K DB checks, I now split the generated codes into multiple chunks of 1000 codes and issue an INSERT IGNORE batch query within a transaction.

If the affected rows are as many as the items (1000 in this case) I know there wasn't a collision and I can commit the transaction. Otherwise I need to rollback the chunk and generate another 1000 codes.